# Create developer sandbox from Jenkins

Tags: sandbox, jenkins, developer-productivity, sdlc

I know how to create them manually through the interface (it is really easy)
setup > sandbox > new sandbox > and follow the GUI.

Is there an API or a script that would allow me to create a sandbox other than using the GUI. I would like to call that API or script from our build server (Jenkins) and allocate the sandboxes that way.

Comment: I think it is possible using tooling API. Check this link: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_sandboxinfo.htm

Comment: Also watch out for "Scratch Orgs" which AFAIK will be available in the summer as part of [Salesforce DX](https://www.salesforce.com/products/platform/products/salesforce-dx/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [SandboxInfo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_sandboxinfo.htm) via the Tooling API against your production org.

> Represents a sandbox.
>
> SandboxInfo enqueues a sandbox for creation or refresh. A create operation on SandboxInfo represents creation of a new sandbox, and an update represents refresh of an existing sandbox. For every create or update, a SandboxProcess is automatically created and is used for monitoring the sandbox copy process.

Also check [SandboxProcess](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_sandboxprocess.htm):

> Represents the sandbox copy process for a SandboxInfo record.
>
> When you create a SandboxInfo record, a corresponding SandboxProcess record is created. The latest SandboxProcess record for a SandboxInfo record represents the current state of the sandbox.

These were introduced in [Winter '16](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_api_tooling.htm) to allow you to create and refresh sandboxes.

The SandboxInfo will need the Template ID from the Sandbox Template (PartitionLevelScheme - keyprefix [1ps](http://www.fishofprey.com/2011/09/obscure-salesforce-object-key-prefixes.html#1ps)).